# Crashlytics error - This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I have two build flavors in gradle but for some reason whenever i change the following flag to false i get the titled error message:

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

the error itself complete is below:

```
Process: com.mobile.myapp.staging, PID: 5439
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.mobile.myapp.UI.myappApplication: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:234)
at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
at com.mobile.myapp.UI.base.BaseApplication.setupExceptionHandling(BaseApplication.java:51)
at com.mobile.myapp.UI.myappApplication.onCreate(myappApplication.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
```

And this is how I initialize crashlytics in my Application subclass:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

what i am trying to do is have control over whether or not a crashlytics can run or not per flavor. lets say i want flavor1 not to run crashlytics i thought i could use that gradle flag and set it to false. am i missing something ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Addition to answer of [Todd Burner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845571/3557894)

Be carefull with `BuildConfig.DEBUG`. IDE can auto-import it from

```
com.crashlytics.android.BuildConfig (= false)
```

instead of your app config

```
${app_package}.BuildConfig
```

**UPDATE**

Providing an example on the request of j2emanue

```
    ...
    import com.fiot.ot.BuildConfig             <- should be
    import com.crashlytics.android.BuildConfig <- my IDE automatically imported 

    fun initFabric(context: Context) {
        val core = CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()
        val kit = Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build()
        Fabric.with(context, kit)
    }
```

Where `com.fiot.ot` package name of my app

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: anwyay to disable crashlytics per flavor yet ?

Comment: I guess below approach should work (didn't check by myself) 


`CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("myFlavor")).build()`

Comment: You got it. This is the answer i wanted if you want to post 1. Thanks

Comment: Same as @j2emanue, did not realize that I imported the wrong BuildConfig class. Thank you so much....

Comment: Where to put this? I set ext.enableCrashlytics = false for debug build and use your code in the app onCreate() method but the app crash before onCreate() was called. Thanks!

Comment: To disable in debug mode is not good option. in my case i used two accounts and use manifest variable according to build type.
Important point to note. each variant should be signed to make it work

Comment: I've followed the docs from the site: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html
And still app crashes, this doesn't work for me... any suggestions

Answer (score 76):

Maybe missing apply plugin fabric

I added this line on top of file `app/build.gradle` resolved my issues!

> apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Comment: This is correct! This is for app-level `build.gradle`.

Comment: After writing this line, getting WARNING : `WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.`

Comment: @DaoLQ when I add that option everything works well when I build the debug version but on the CI the build fails because it can't find the io.Fabric plugin

Comment: We must add this line apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

Answer (score 36):

Whenever I set

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

my app crashes with

```
io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException

This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up, install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
```

What seems to work for me is that I have to disable automatic initialization of Crashlytics by adding this line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

Then I manually initialize Crashlytics in the onCreate() method of my Application subclass, use BuildConfig.DEBUG to decide whether to disable CrashlyticsCore, and call Fabric.with().  In fact, I no longer set

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

at all.  It all seems to work to me.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too. Some related Google documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?authuser=0#enable_debug_mode

Comment: Many thanks. Seems like https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds which forces us to add "ext.enableCrashlytics = false" necessarily just confuses people

Answer (score 12):

Todd from Fabric. You will get this error unless you also disable Fabric at run time.

```
    // Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
    .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
    .build();

// Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Check out this link for more details: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#disable-crashlytics-for-debug-builds

Comment: ok, actually i wanted to disable it per flavor not per debug status.  but if nothing else i'll do it this way.

Comment: Where to put this? I set ext.enableCrashlytics = false for debug build and use your code in the app onCreate() method but the app crash before onCreate() was called. Thanks!

Comment: @KGBird shared the right answer which actually works! Sadly, this answer and the way mentioned in the docs doesn't work :(

Comment: @Todd Why is this even NOT INCLUDED on the official documentation? There's a ton of implementation you can found online how to do this very core task. Please be consistent with your code

Comment: @Todd: This is not working. I followed the same instructions from fabric but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks nice, but not working. That's great actually simple documentation is not working, see the irony :))

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you add in

> app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

I also have

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
```

in the

> project gradle dependencies

and add the Crashlytics api in the strings, signup in the [Crashlytics Site](https://www.fabric.io/)

Comment: don't forget it again. actually you can add their plugin to the android studio, I understand it does all the work for you. Dig from their site though or from the Studio Plugins

Comment: YUS. very important

Answer (score 6):

### **For Xamarin Android (Fabric is Deprecated - EOL)**

You need to have the following not to receive the above error:

1. Include the NuGet packages:

   - Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics **[by Microsoft]**
   - Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics.Core **[by Microsoft]**
   - Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics.Beta **[by Microsoft]**
   - Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics.Answers **[by Microsoft]**
2. Add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file within `<application>`:

   `<meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="<FABRIC_API_KEY>" />`

   - *(You can obtain the key when you do the onboarding on https://fabric.io/onboard)*
   - or go to https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install after you have signed in, you should see your key there in the tutorial.
3. Add this line in `Resources/values/Strings.xml` resource file:

   `<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">15</string>`
4. Add this line in `MainApplication.cs` or `YourActivity.cs` in `OnCreate()`:

   `Fabric.Fabric.With(this, new Crashlytics.Crashlytics());`

Your app should build and run past the initialization line without any issues. Only problem I have with it is the fact that there is one more place you need to update the Build version of your app everytime your release.

---

### **EDIT :**

As far as I'm experiencing, the one value is required but not used at all. You do not actually have to increase the build number in `Strings.xml`, it picks up the build number from the app automatically, so you should be fine just to leave the value at:
`<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">1</string>`

If you experience it differently for Xamarin, please comment below.

Answer (score 1):

In My case this got worked.

so, this is the top level project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

and this is the build.gradle for app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your application package name"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

and at last "clean build" and all was set for me.